# Blender->Unity Import Animation Failing by Overlapping Mesh Objects

Tags: unity, blender, 3d-meshes, 3d-modeling

I'm new to both Unity and Blender. I created this penguin 3d model, rigged it up and animated it in Blender and all looked good.

When I imported it into Unity, I noticed that this idle animation did not appear to be working correctly. As the body moves, the body mesh overlaps the belly mesh and covers a portion of it.

[image]

This is not the case when viewing the animation from blender 2.9.

[image]

The belly uses a shrinkwrap modifier with the body as a target.

Is this a problem with Unity import, or how I modeled this penguin in Blender? Can anyone see what I have done wrong here? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: weight painting?

Comment: I have tried adjusting the weights of the belly to be influenced more. But it has adverse effects. For some reason, the animation in blender looks fine without doing any adjustments to the weight.

Comment: Keep in mind that "shrink wrap" is not a modifier that exists in Unity's animation system. So if that modifier is doing some of the work to adjust the shape of this object during the animation, you'll need to bake out that shape change to skeletal animation keyframes (or shape keys) to export it for use in-game. Generally in games we avoid having two closely parallel surfaces like this, as it can cause z-fighting or unnecessary overdraw.